# Directives angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i'm really new on angular.
Im using angular 1.6, and i need to do some changes on a existing app.

As i could search, the previous developer was using http://www.codingdrama.com/bootstrap-markdown/ to have a textarea with some text options and a preview. My task now is to override the preview button to call our API with the text inserted and API return some result. On docs of that markdown I added up I found this.

onPreview: function(e) {
    var previewContent

```
if (e.isDirty()) {
  var originalContent = e.getContent()

  previewContent = "Prepended text here..."
         + "\n"
         + originalContent
         + "\n"
         +"Apended text here..."
} else {
  previewContent = "Default content"
}

return previewContent
```

},

So i started to override that:

```
   app.directive("markdowntextarea", ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        link: function (el_scope, element, attr) {
            var previewContent = "preview";
            element.markdown(
                {
                    autofocus: false,
                    savable: false,

                    onPreview: function (e) {
                        console.log('1');
                        if (e.isDirty()) {
                            console.log('2!!')
                            var originalContent = e.getContent();
                            $http({
                                url: '/api/markdown/',
                                data: {"body": originalContent, "actual_format": "md", "desire_format": "html"},
                                method: 'POST'
                            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                                console.log(response.data.content);
                                previewContent = response.data.content;
                            });
                        }else{
                            console.log('3')
                            previewContent = "";
                        }
                        previewContent = 'test';
                       return previewContent;
                    },
                });
        }
    }
}]);
```

I can't find the error I have, but the previewContent always return "preview". From API side is ok, and the `response.data.content` is also correct.

Have no idea what to do next

Comment: @gus27 Semicolons are optional in javascript.

Comment: read about promises and async calls...

Comment: ok, i move the previewContent to outside of IF

Comment: Have you tried to put the line `previewContent = this.response.data.content;` in the `successCallback` function?

Comment: yeah you should probably be running this after you get a response from your api, other wise it's just returning previewContent while it's still set to "preview"

Comment: @gus27 yes, and i got Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Comment: Use `previewContent = response.data.content;` instead of `previewContent = this.response.data.content;` inside of `successCallback`.

Comment: @gus27 you understood the problem of your answer ?

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the bit about writing good titles. The title as it stands is almost useless, considering the tags you have on the question.

Answer (score 2):

The challenge is that you execute an asynchronous function and want to return it's value. In your code example you already returned from the `onPreview` function while the async function is still executed in the background. In AngularJS you can use [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) to solve this kind of problem: *"A service that helps you run functions asynchronously, and use their return values (or exceptions) when they are done processing"*.

**BUT**: As far I can see from the [source](https://github.com/toopay/bootstrap-markdown/blob/master/js/bootstrap-markdown.js) the markdown component does not support promises. The `onPreview` method expects a string to be returned. The only option is to wait inside `onPreview` until the AJAX request returns - which is strongly discouraged. So IMHO it is not possible to use an AJAX request inside of `onPreview`.

**IF** the bootstrap-markdown would support promises you could try this:

```
app.directive("markdowntextarea", ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) { // inject $q
...
onPreview: function (e) {
    console.log('im here!!');
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (e.isDirty()) {
        var originalContent = e.getContent();
        $http({
            url: '/api/markdown/',
            data: {"body": originalContent, "code": "a"},
            method: 'POST'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log("successCallback", response.data.content);
            deferred.resolve(response.data.content);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log("errorCallback");
            deferred.reject("error");
        });
    } else {
        // quando esta vazio
        deferred.resolve("");
    }
    return deferred.promise;
},
...
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mxonvyrc/) that demonstrates the concept. It's an update of Dave Kerr's [AngularJS Promises - The Definitive Guide Part 2 - JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dwmkerr/LeZU4/) to AngularJS 1.6.

Comment: It still returns "preview"

Comment: still it doesn't call my api :/

Comment: Hi, it still returns the originalContent. I have no idea why. here:                                 console.log("successCallback", response.data.content); -> I got the right response from api.

Comment: d {$$state: Object}
 0
 Object {status: 0}
 successCallback from api!!!   Some  tests I did, it looks like the response from api comes after

Comment: @62009030 I updated my answer: According to the source code of bootstrap-markdown I think it is not possible to use an AJAX request inside `onPreview`.

Comment: Yes I see that is not possible :/ Do you know some different plugin for angularjs for markdown edit and preview, for example as gitlab has ? thanks